# Javascript Loads but does not work in Magento 1.9

Tags: javascript, magento

Just getting into Magento. I have added a menu and need it to work as it does in the Pen

http://s.codepen.io/WallyNally/debug/dWqGEp/yoMZEQWedYdk

Magento *is* loading the JS and CSS files as confirmed in sourcecode. The style displays properly. As a double check, in the JS file I have included `var MyVariable = "Exists!";`. Going to the console in the live dev page, I can type 'MyVariable' and its value is properly returned. There are no errors thrown or displayed.

However, the hover event does not exist. Namely the two mouseenter event triggers.

Here is a working excerpt of the desired javascript:

```
jQuery("#categories a").mouseenter(function() {
    let subcateg = "sub-" + jQuery(this).attr("id");
    let active = jQuery(".subcateg-active");
    let current = jQuery("#" + subcateg);

    if (active.length == 1) {
        jQuery(active).toggleClass("subcateg-active").fadeOut(150, function(){
             jQuery(current).toggleClass("subcateg-active").fadeIn(180);
        });
    } else if (active.length == 0){
        jQuery(current).toggleClass("subcateg-active").fadeIn(180);
    }

    if (active.length > 1) {
        jQuery(active).css("display", "none").removeClass("option-active");
        jQuery(current).toggleClass("subcateg-active").fadeIn(120);
    }
});
```

var MyVariable = "Exists!";

Here is the dev site (link will not be permanent, so an image is attached as well):

http://atlas3.netsos.com/
[image]

Any Magento savants know what went awry?

Answer (score 1):

Now I think that there can be 2 reasons:

- First: I don't see any category items, so, do you sure that ""#categories a" selector works (element with ID categories holds some link tags ?)?
- Second: JS script, where you trying to hung events on some html elements, should be executed after element on which this event must be hunged will be added to document. So, try to execute your script after document loaded.

Example:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    // Here your JS code
});
```